# Retrieve nodes from XML belonging to a specific node

Tags: c#, xml, nodes

I have a XML like this:

```
    <ITEM>
  <RACES>
    <TAB>
      <NUMBER>1</NUMBER>
      <A></A>
      <B></B>
    </TAB>
    <TAB>
      <NUMBER>2</NUMBER>
      <A></A>
      <B></B>
    </TAB>
  </RACES>
</ITEM>
```

is it possible to retrieve as XmlNodeList all the As and Bs nodes that belong to only TAB with NUMBER 1?

I use the following codes, but it gives me of course 2 nodes. I want only 1 node :

```
XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/ITEM/RACES/TAB/A");
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Please mark this answer as accepted. Side note - I would use Linq to XML

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I wish I could mark that comment, as it is hilarious.

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair I use XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/ITEM/RACES/TAB/A") but it gives me of course 2 nodes. I want only 1 node

Comment: `xml.SelectNodes("/ITEM/RACES/TAB[NUMBER=1]/A")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do xmlDocument.SelectNodes(expression)

where if you need both nodes A & B

```
expression = @"//TAB[NUMBER=1]/A|//TAB[NUMBER=1]/B"
```

if you need only A node seperately

```
expression = @"//TAB[NUMBER=1]/A"
```

if you need only B node seperately

```
expression = @"//TAB[NUMBER=1]/B"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as below:

```
XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/RACES/TAB");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
  int num = xn["NUMBER"].InnerText;
  if(num==1)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Nodes: {0} {1}", xn["A"], xn["B"]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend Linq to Xml.  You can knock it out in one statement:

```
var nodes_A_and_B = XDocument.Parse(xml)
                     .Descendants("TAB")
                     .Where(t => t.Element("NUMBER").Value == "1")
                     .Select(t => new 
                             {
                                A = t.Element("A"), 
                                B = t.Element("B")
                             });
```

Answer (score 0):

it will be return what you need

> Happy coding

```
  var items = XElement.Parse(xmlelemet)
                        .Elements("RACES")
                        .Elements("TAB")
                        .Where(n => n.Attribute("NUMBER").Value == 1)
                        .Elements();
```