# Get information of one specific element by ID out of multiple XML

Tags: c#, xml

I am new to C# so this might be an easy one..

Question after code:

```
<root>
  <MachineConfigurations>
    <Configuration id="VPM3Config">
      <MachineName>VPM 3</MachineName>
      <Options>
        <RequiredMachineOptions>Rollenband</RequiredMachineOptions>
        <ExtraMachineOptions>Rollenband</ExtraMachineOptions>
      </Options>
    </Configuration>
  </MachineConfigurations>

  <MachineConfigurations>
    <Configuration id="VPM5Config">
      <MachineName>VPM 5</MachineName>
      <Options>
        <RequiredMachineOptions>Handmatige Oplegger</RequiredMachineOptions>
        <ExtraMachineOptions>Sheetdispenser</ExtraMachineOptions>
      </Options>
    </Configuration>
  </MachineConfigurations>
```

I would like to get the options specific to the configuration with ID "VPM 3". If I use the Descendants("Options") I get all the options of the XML document..
I need something like: Get all RequiredMachineOptions where ConfigurationType = VPM3CONFIG

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve nodes from XML belonging to a specific node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30125027/retrieve-nodes-from-xml-belonging-to-a-specific-node)

Comment: Couldn't find something like that, thank you!

Comment: Can't seem to work it out though.. Can you give some advice?

Comment: Which XML API are you using? `XmlReader`, `XmlDocument`, `System.Linq.Xml` or something else?

Comment: I allready use XDocument in a previous piece of code.. I adjusted my question, does it clear up things?

Comment: Try following : List<XElement> VPM3 = doc.Descendants("Configuration").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("id") == "VPM3Config").ToList();

Comment: @jdwegn That gives me count=0, it won't find any

Comment: Then your sample xml doesn't match your actual xml cause I tried @jdweng 's code and it did return the expected node

Comment: You are right, my fault! I was changing things up to try other examples.. But now my next problem, I want to add the RequiredMachineOptions to a list<string>.. Any advice again? Sorry for my lack of experience..

Comment: Figured it out, thanks guys!

Comment: Try this :  List<string> requiredMachineOptions = VPM3.Descendants("RequiredMachineOptions").Select(x => (string)x).ToList();

Comment: Try code at this link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58183590/8404323